# how to break the internet connection with code?

Tags: c++, windows

hey i know that on some computers you can cut off the wifi with a buttion and i want to do that with my desktop but it's not wireless. is there a way to in code block my computer from the internet then unblock later. anyway i can do this?

Comment: Maybe if you explain in more detail what you actually want to do, somebody can answer your question. Are you trying to prevent all network access, or just the Internet?

Comment: For windows, you could always just crash the system. ;)

Comment: to the internet i guess.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [WMI - Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390385.aspx) to disable network connections.

WMI is visual basic / scripting friendly COM-technology based API and doesn't provide greate abilities though. But hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use [`IpReleaseAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366056%28VS.85%29.aspx) to cut the connection, and [`IpRenewAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366057%28VS.85%29.aspx) to re-start it. Another possibility would be to use [`SetIfEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366362%28VS.85%29.aspx) to disable/enable the network interface.

Answer (score 0):

A rather brute force way on windows if you're getting your address via DHCP is to just make a call to ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew when you want your access back.

Comment: uhh... could i use that in my program?

Comment: Of course. Just use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to start the ipconfig executable.

Comment: Still, calling external executables to carry out a task that can be done easily with APIs (see Jerry Coffin's answer) is generally bad programming practice.